# How to print variable value in text

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

I want the program to print `A car with number of wheels has been created.
Numbers of wheels = <wheels variable value>`.

I tried to use place holder as in `C#` {0} or {1}: `System.out.println("A car with {0} wheels created", wheels);`

Comment: `System.out.println("A car with " + wheels + " wheels has been created.");`

Comment: That, or as you already mentioned placeholders: use String.format()

Comment: or loggers. `System.out`s are more of a debug, wip activity

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `+` as a way to concatenate strings, like so:

`System.out.println("A car with " + wheels + " wheels has been created.")` where wheels is your variable

Comment: ```System,out.printf("A car with %d wheels has been created.%n", wheels)``` seems to me easier to read, especially in cases where more than one insertion is wanted.